# Android Google Maps V2 Marker Click Stuckes The Map View

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

Im developing an android Tab app using FragmentTabs, A Child Fragment class uses Google Maps V2,

```
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Once i clicked on a map marker, i need to move to another Child Fragment Class,

```
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                 
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, new FragmentClass());
                transaction.commit();
                getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            }
        });
```

But when i clicked on the marker it freeze my app, i couldn't find any exceptions either..

Comment: have you tried `FragmentManager` instead of `FragmentTransaction`

Comment: thanks, problem is, i already developed whole app in FragmentTransaction so cant change it for this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();                          
                YourActivity activity = new YourActivity();

                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, activity);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
```